Exception in SSMS: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0'
I'm encountering an issue in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) when trying to perform certain actions. The full error message I receive is as follows:
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (System.Memory)

BUTTONS: OK

Error screenshot
SSMS version

I found that in the SSMS project exists System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 but SSMS search for 4.1.3
